# two steps create/upload a file to hdfs with webhdfs/httpfs

Tags: hdfs, httpclient, webhdfs

I used `apache-httpclient` and `webhdfs` to create and upload a file(.jar) to HDFS. At last, it responded with a 201 and content-length=0.

But when I found the file on the HDFS, its length was 0. What's wrong? And what should I do to upload the jar file?

The REST API just like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXj5u.png)

Comment: I had finished it by using Put method again